# проблема с добавлением текстуры к obj в Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, obj

Проблема в том, что я пытаюсь добавить текстуру (накладываю на материал).

Ошибку не выдаёт, просто не отображается текстура

Когда я пытаюсь добавить текстуру "Морда на белом фоне" - сущность становиться просто белой

А когда добавляю текстуру с "кучей зелёных листьев" - сущность становиться залита сплошным тёмным зелёным цветом, без всяких признаков листьев.

```
var cylinder_texture = new THREE.Texture();
var loader_cylinder = new THREE.ImageLoader();

loader_cylinder.load('1.jpg', function(image){
    cylinder_texture.image = image; //пробовал и image.content, но тогда объект становиться никаким, прозрачным
    cylinder_texture.needsUpdate = true;
});

var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
    console.log( item, loaded, total );
};

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'js/1.obj', function ( object ) {

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            var cylinder_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

            child.material = cylinder_material;
            child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            child.material.map = cylinder_texture;

        }

    } );

    object.position.x = -30;
    object.position.y = 130;
    object.position.z = 250;
    object.rotation.x = 20 * Math.PI / 180;
    object.rotation.y = -50 * Math.PI / 180;
    object.rotation.z = 0 * Math.PI / 180;
    object.scale.x = 30;
    object.scale.y = 20;
    object.scale.z = 20;
    obj = object
    scene.add( obj );

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
} );
```

[image: так всё выглядит]

В редакторе [(редактор)](https://threejs.org/editor/) я к типу MeshBasicMaterial добавил картинку в Map и всё сработало, но с кодом не хочет работать, подскажите что не так?

Comment: а модель в файле `1.obj` - она откуда экспортирована?

Comment: Из Blender экспортирована (овальный цилиндр)

Comment: Такая беда с текстурой бывает, когда нарушены (или отсутсвуют) uv-координаты. С Blender не сталкивался, но, судя по примерам в сети, при экспорте нужно ставить "галку" рядом с пунктом "UVs" [картинка](https://i0.wp.com/www.electronicarmory.com/app/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/blender-face-materials.png)

Comment: Спасибо, я освоил как в Blender сделать текстуру и всё получилось